# Conceptually what happens to a php array if all its elements are unset?

Tags: php, arrays, unset

Conceptually what happens to an array that has all of its elements unset? Please see the below  code for and example:

```
$ourArray = array(
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4"
);

foreach($ourArray as $key => $value){
    unset($ourArray[$key])
}
```

In this case is the entire array considered unset? Or is the array considered empty?

Would **$ourArray == array()** or **null**?

Comment: Havde you tried `var_dump()`ing it?

Comment: Try var_dump() when ever you have to debug PHP script. In case of your question the element simply gets deleted.

Comment: The var_dump() returns an empty array. That would indicate that the element exists and is not itself unset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case is the entire array considered unset?

**No**

> Or is the array considered empty?

**Yes**

By the way you can try out your own example with these testcases

```
<?php

echo isset($ourArray)?1:0; // "prints" 0 since array doesn't contain anything
echo empty($ourArray)?1:0; // "prints" 1 since elements are not there !

$ourArray = array(
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4"
);
echo empty($ourArray)?1:0; // "prints" 0 since elements are there !

foreach($ourArray as $key => $value){
    unset($ourArray[$key]);
}

echo isset($ourArray)?1:0; // "prints" 1 since the array is set , only the elements are emptied
echo empty($ourArray)?1:0; // "prints" 1 since the array elements are empty
```

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. I will logic test based on the array being  considered empty. This will give the results I need.

Answer (score 3):

The **unset()** method destroys the variable passed.
So passing all the array keys **unset()** destroys them (not the array) and leaves the actual array empty.

**1. Unsetting all the elements**

So doing this will result in an empty $array

```
foreach ($array as $k => $value)
    unset($array[$k];

var_dump($array) //array {}
```

**2. Unsetting the whole array**

However passing the whole array to the **unset()** method will destroy the whole array and will will result in $array to be NULL

```
unset($array)

var_dump($array) // NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

The keys are not shuffled or renumbered. The unset() key is simply removed and the others remain. So the array still exists, only the element gets deleted. Yes, and the array will remain.

Answer (score 1):

It should be an array without any values in it. So technically it's the same as array()

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $ourArray = array(
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4"
);

foreach($ourArray as $key => $value){
    unset($ourArray[$key]);
}
var_dump($ourArray);

?>
```

**output**

```
array(0) { }
```